# When does $A^{-1}=A^T$ holds true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Is it true that if $D$ is a diagonal matrix and $AXA^T=D$ then $A^{-1}=A^T$?

Referring to my recent question which I struggle to find an answer to [Help With Matrices Whitening Problem in Random Vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3505181/help-with-matrices-whitening-problem-in-random-vectors)

EDIT: |D| > 0 of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't if you take $A = 2Id$ and $X = Id$
You have that $AXA^{T} = 4Id = D$ a diagonal matrix, but $A^{-1} \not= A^{T}$

Comment: You rock! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Thank you SO SOOOOOOOOO MUCH!!!!!! I understood the problem in my root question ^_^. Will update now.

Comment: I'm glad for you, you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

No. Suppose that both $A$ and $D$ are the null matrix. Then $D$ is diagonal and $AXA^T=D$ (whatever $X$ is), but $A$ has no inverse.

Comment: I edited. |D|>0 I'm trying to reach my mistake n a bigger problem.

Comment: It is inappropriate to change a question after having got an answer.

Answer (score 1):

For example

$$ \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & -2 \\
 -2 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right) $$

Just from solving

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a+b+c+d & b+d \\
 c+d & d \\
\end{array}
\right) = D $$

Comment: Here it holds true